# Where exactly do the logs of kubernetes pods come from (at the container level)?

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, containers, kubectl

I'm looking to redirect some logs from a command run with `kubectl exec` to that pod's logs, so that they can be read with `kubectl logs <pod-name>` (or really, `/var/log/containers/<pod-name>.log`). I can see the logs I need as output when running the command, and they're stored inside a separate log directory inside the running container.

Redirecting the output (i.e. `>> logfile.log`) to the file which I thought was mirroring what is in `kubectl logs <pod-name>` does not update that container's logs, and neither does redirecting to stdout.

When calling `kubectl logs <pod-name>`, my understanding is that kubelet gets them from it's internal `/var/log/containers/` directory.  But what determines which logs are stored there? Is it the same process as the way logs get stored inside any other docker container?

Is there a way to examine/trace the logging process, or determine where these logs are coming from?

Answer (score 31):

Logs from the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` of containers in the pod are captured and stored inside files in /var/log/containers. This is what is presented when `kubectl log` is run.

In order to understand why output from commands run by kubectl exec is not shown when running `kubectl log`, let's have a look how it all works with an example:

First launch a pod running ubuntu that are sleeping forever:

```
$> kubectl run test --image=ubuntu --restart=Never -- sleep infinity
```

Exec into it

```
$> kubectl exec -it test bash
```

Seen from inside the container it is the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` of PID 1 that are being captured. When you do a `kubectl exec` into the container a new process is created living alongside PID 1:

```
root@test:/# ps -auxf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         7  0.0  0.0  18504  3400 pts/0    Ss   20:04   0:00 bash
root        19  0.0  0.0  34396  2908 pts/0    R+   20:07   0:00  \_ ps -auxf
root         1  0.0  0.0   4528   836 ?        Ss   20:03   0:00 sleep infinity
```

Redirecting to `STDOUT` is not working because `/dev/stdout` is a symlink to the process accessing it (`/proc/self/fd/1` rather than `/proc/1/fd/1`).

```
root@test:/# ls -lrt /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov  5 20:03 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
```

In order to see the logs from commands run with `kubectl exec` the logs need to be redirected to the streams that are captured by the kubelet (`STDOUT` and `STDERR` of pid 1). This can be done by redirecting output to `/proc/1/fd/1`.

```
root@test:/# echo "Hello" > /proc/1/fd/1
```

Exiting the interactive shell and checking the logs using `kubectl logs` should now show the output

```
$> kubectl logs test
Hello
```

Comment: thanks for this!

Comment: This answer should be accepted, thanks for this!

Comment: i am receiving the error "/proc/1/fd/1: Permission denied". In ls -la i saw that the /1 folder has mysql permissions. Do you know how can i solve this?

Comment: @vitorEstevam You should probably be root. Try using `sudo` or `su` and then echo toward the file.

Comment: Excellent! This is how it works `./my_app >> /proc/1/fd/1`