# Python on docker to print out to stdout

Tags: python, docker, logging

I'm running a docker container that executes commands with server. 
It then logs the output to files.
I have another docker that runs every few minutes and pick up everything from `docker log {name}`. 
I'm looking for a way to read the executions log files and print it to `STDOUT` for the logger service to pick the data to. 
I tried something like:
`subprocess.call("cat {latest_file}".format(latest_file=latest_file), shell=True)` but it only print it to console whilst running.

my question is: can I add my own files/directories to the docker logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know the name of the log file beforehand, you can let the application continue to log as is (i.e to a file) and symlink that file to `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/stderr`

This is a quite common solution, for example [nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/8921999083def7ba43a06fabd5f80e4406651353/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L21-L23) does it

```
# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

**EDIT:**
Please note that this will only work if the applications that do logging is running as PID 0. If you have forked a process or similar, you will have to explicitly write to the stdout/stderr file descriptor of PID 1  (available under `/proc/1/fd`

```
# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /proc/1/fd/2 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

(Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716574/where-exactly-do-the-logs-of-kubernetes-pods-come-from-at-the-container-level/58718841#58718841) for more details)

Comment: `echo 1 > /proc/1/fd/1` made my day!