# Azure AKS - how to mount a volume on a common disk for pods running on nodes from different availability zones?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, logstash, filebeat

I'm running an AKS cluster on 3 nodes in different availability zones (for HA). There's an API running on it with pods on each cluster.

The plan is to add FileBeat as a DaemonSet (one pod on each node), and Logstash collecting the logs from each FileBeat instance. I chose DaemonSet over SidecarProxy pattern to consume less ressources on the node.

For FileBeat being able to read the logs from the API pods, I wanted to mount a volume on a managed azure disk on which the APIs can write their log files and from which FileBeat can read them.

The Azure Disk is of course only residing in one zone. So the problem is that the volume can't be attached if the node is not in the same AZ than the disk:

```
AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "logging-persistent-volume" : Retriable: false, RetryAfter: 0s, HTTPStatusCode: 400, RawError: Retriable: false, RetryAfter: 0s, HTTPStatusCode: 400, RawError: { "error": { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "Disk /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/<disk name> cannot be attached to the VM because it is not in zone '3'." } }
```

I'm quite new to Kubernetes and Azure. So, is there a way to have a shared volume for all API pods in this kind of environment?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To answer your question**:

You can add a storage solution in between which manages Azure Disks, and then create your volumes using that storage solution instead. An example would be `Ceph`, and you can use [rook operator](https://rook.io) to set that up.

**To solve your problem**:

If you let your API log to stdout, kubernetes will write those log files in a disk at a specific location. Filebeat can then read from this location on each node and send your logs wherever you want them to be. This is the standard practice used for logging in the kubernetes environment, unless you have a specific need to write those logs to a volume, I wouldn't recommend that.

According to the [filebeat docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html):

> You deploy Filebeat as a DaemonSet to ensure there’s a running instance on each node of the cluster.
>
> The Docker logs host folder (/var/lib/docker/containers) is mounted on
> the Filebeat container. Filebeat starts an input for the files and
> begins harvesting them as soon as they appear in the folder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Hazim! So you would log everything to stdout, redirect it with Filebeat to LogStash and let Logstash do the filtering to match each line to the corresponding ElasticSearch index?

Comment: Yes exactly, log everything to stdout (standard practice for 12 factor app*). kubernetes/docker will place those logs as files in a specific place (default is /var/lib/docker/containers). Configure filebeat to read from there and send them to logstash. 

* https://12factor.net

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (at least that I am aware of) to mount disks in one AZ to a VM in another, which is also what the error message indicates.

In addition, [Azure Disks are mounted as `ReadWriteOnce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage#azure-disks) it will only be available to one pod at a time

> Since Azure Disks are mounted as ReadWriteOnce, they're only available
> to a single pod. For storage volumes that can be accessed by multiple
> pods simultaneously, use Azure Files.

In order for multiple pods to share the same volume across multiple zones you need to select another storage provider.

Azure Files is an option if it meets your performance requirements etc. See more in [Storage options for applications in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage)

## An alternate approach

Since you are taking the approach of a deamonset where Filebeat runs once on every node, you could mount the host folder `/var/lib/docker/containers` into the file beat container and forward logs from there.

This requires your applications to log to `STDOUT` or `STDERR` though, as it is those logs that end up under `/var/lib/docker/containers`. It is also those logs you see when you run `kubectl logs` or `docker logs`. If your applications currently log to the file system you will either have to reconfigure them to log to `STDOUT`/`STDERR` instead, or symlink the log file to `/dev/stdout` (or `/proc/1/fd`, see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147411/7146596)

This way each filebeat pod is responsible to forward logs from the node it is running on.

This approach is described in the [Run filebeat on Kubernetes guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html#_kubernetes_deploy_manifests)